# How to remove the <![if !supportLists]> tags when using TinyMCE

Tags: html, ms-word, tinymce, editor

I know that these tags are coming from MS-Word (when copying and pasting).
I check the another questions here, and all the solutions involving using the "paste" plugin don't work.

Any idea how to tell TinyMCE during init to hide (or remove) those tags?

Answer (score 1):

`TinyMce` has an `init` function that you can call that has a variety of parameters it will accept. With regards to your question, the specific ones you want here are to do with paste:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    plugins: 'paste',
    paste_remove_spans: true,
    paste_remove_styles: true,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true
});
```

`paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste` will get rid of all almost all of the rubbish that is copied from, for example, MS-Word. You could also have a look at [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) parameter also, where you can specify what `HTML` markup is allowed

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I used <textarea> instead of <div> for the tinyMCE. textarea (regardless to tinymce) converts strange (word) elements such as <!supportList> to text, instead of hiding them like a well-behaved div.